# Anchor tag not appending to URL Action C# MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to debug. I have some Bootstrap Tabs, that have Action Links in like so:

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "viewamendments" &&
                 controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewAmendments", "SongManagement")' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Old Song">Old Song</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But for some reason when I go to the URL /SongManagement/ViewAmendments the tab is styled correctly but in the Console using Chrome it's not appending the href attribute instead of its showing:

```
<a data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Old Song">Old Song</a>
```

I have cleaned the solution in VS2017 and Rebuilt it, I have also Cleared the browser cache and hard reset. Also tried in Incognito.

Any advice on what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was due to the controller name, not being found. A simple change, but usually it won't append the href tag when it can't find the method in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

can you please try with

```
data-target='@Url.Action("ViewAmendments", "SongManagement")'
```

Add this attribute in your anchor tag and try again.

Comment: or also data-load-url= support in bootstrap for redirection.

Comment: have you tried with  data-load-url="@Url.Action("ViewAmendments", "SongManagement")"